# onMapReady() method calling before building GoogleApiClient - Getting LatLong 0.0

Tags: android, google-maps, location, android-mapview, latitude-longitude

Hello I am getting LatLong in may app as below :

Created a method in my fragment to build GoogleApiClient :

```
 private synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
    MyApp.getGoogleApiHelper().setConnectionListener(new GoogleApiHelper.ConnectionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
            //this function will call whenever google api connected or already connected when setting listener
            //You are connected do what ever you want
            //Like i get last known location
            try {
                if (!Constant.checkPermission(mContext, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {
                    Constant.requestPermission(mContext, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST);
                } else {
                    if (Constant.isOnline(mContext)) {
                        mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
                        mCurrentLatitude = mLastLocation.getLatitude();
                        mCurrentLongitude = mLastLocation.getLongitude();
                        locationUpdate();
                    } else {
                        Constant.displayToast(mContext, getResources().getString(R.string.msg_internet));
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

**OnMapReady()** method is as below : Calling loadDefault() method to load current location.

```
public void onMapReady(final GoogleMap googleMap) {
    loadDefault(googleMap);
}
```

My loadDefault() method is as below :

```
private void loadDefault(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    try {
        if (Prefrences.checkPref(mContext, NEAR_ME_SEARCH))
            googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(Prefrences.getPref(mContext, NEAR_ME_LAT)), Double.parseDouble(Prefrences.getPref(mContext, NEAR_ME_LNG))), 8));
        else
            googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(mCurrentLatitude, mCurrentLongitude), 8f));
    } catch (MalformedParameterizedTypeException e) {
        handleException(mContext, e);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        handleException(mContext, e);
    }
}
```

But, I am getting **mCurrentLaltitude** and **mCurrentLongitude** 0.0 at below line inside loadDefault() method.

```
googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(mCurrentLatitude, mCurrentLongitude), 8f));
```

please, provide solution. thanks.

**EDIT** :

```
 private void initialization(View rootView, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    try {
        mModelBarList = BarListModel.getBarListInstance();
        if (!Constant.checkPermission(mContext, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {
            Constant.requestPermission(mContext, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST);
        } else {
            if (Constant.isOnline(mContext)) {
                mGoogleApiClient = MyApp.getGoogleApiHelper().getGoogleApiClient();
                buildGoogleApiClient();
            } else {
                Constant.displayToast(mContext, getResources().getString(R.string.msg_internet));
            }
        }

        mMapView = (MapView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.map);
        mMapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mMapView.onResume();
        mMapView.getMapAsync(MapFragment.this);
}
```

Comment: Who is calling the method `buildGoogleApiClient()`?  My guess is that this method either is not being called at all, or is being called after `onMapReady()`.  In my use of Google Maps for Android, I would store my locations in instance state if I needed to persist it across an orientation change or reload.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen , can you please provide correct way of getting the lat lngs(which can be used throughout the class) and initializing the map faster in the above condition?

Comment: I can't give an exact answer because I don't know what you are trying to do.  Load the values when the activity loads, then store them into instance state, at least this is what I do.  Your solution may differ if you are, e.g., getting them from preferences or maybe from a SQLite database.

Comment: hello edited : added initialization() method where i am calling buildGoogleApiClient() method...

Answer (score 0):

When `onMapReady` is called and the map has been loaded, is not sure that google api client is connected, because these two operations executed asynchronously. So you have to add a logic so the ones that finishes first wait until the other is over and then show the coordinates in the map.

Comment: ya thats what i am asking.. any solution ?

Comment: Sorry but i can not provide a copy-past solution. A not so elegant solution is to keep a reference of your map when it is loaded and when you get your coordinates from the google api client then check if mMap!=null and if it is true go on with your map operations. Corespondingly, when your onMapReady is called check if your mCurrentLatitude, mCurrentLongitude != 0 and if true go on